# Fill remaining space with fixed aspect ratio surfaceview

Tags: android

I'd like to layout a view like the following, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so:

- At the bottom of the screen is a regular view, with a fixed size (fill-width and some number of dp for height)
- Filling the remaining vertical space, I would like to place a custom view which inherits from glSurfaceView, with the restriction that it must have a fixed aspect ratio, which will be programatically set, but known before the activity is created. (In this case assume it with be 2:3 w:h).

Here's a little picture of what I'm imagining:

```
 .----------------------. 
 |   .--------------.   |  
 | b |              | b |  
 | g |              | g | 
 |   |              |   |  
 | i |  MySurface   | i | 
 | m |     View     | m | 
 | a |              | a | 
 | g |  (2:3 w:h)   | g | 
 | e |              | e | 
 |   *--------------*   | 
 |.--------------------.| 
 ||                    || 
 ||   SomeOtherView    || 
 ||                    || 
 |*--------------------*| 
 *----------------------*
```

As far as setting up the MySurfaceView, I assume that normal layout_width and layout_height are not going to help me, because I don't know the available screen size until after the screen has been partially laid out, and `SomeOtherView` has been placed.

Is there some function in `MySurfaceView` that I want to override, that for example will pass as arguments the available screen space, and let me decide how to set the width and height of the view?

Is 'inflation' the right term I'm looking for here? I think that has something to do with what I'm looking for, but I don't really know the terminology.

[Updated below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522282/1236185) with the result of my research, and I think a possible correct solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did more research and I think I figured out what I need to do:

The function I was looking to override is `onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec)`, which is called by the parent with suggestions for width and height (see [View.MeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html)). I also set `MySurfaceView` to have a layout_width/height of `wrap_content` in the xml. Then when `onMeasure` gets called I can compute the available aspect ratio and set the width and height of my view as desired.

The second thing I did to make this work was to put my `MySurfaceView` inside of a FrameLayout as the only child. I originally had `MySurfaceView` in a RelativeLayout with the `SomeOtherView` from my image. The problem with the RelativeLayout, is that it would not negotiate the width/height in a way that allowed me to fix the aspect ratio.

`onMeasure` gets called multiple times during measuring, and the way RelativeLayout works is that it first asks the custom view for it's width without telling it the available height, and then later comes back and asks for the height, while the width is locked to what you specified in the first pass (`MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`). This makes it impossible to generate a view of a certain ratio, as you must confirm the width before knowing the available height.

Once inside of the FrameLayout, I didn't have this problem, as the MeasureSpecs passed to `onMeasure` only ever had the restriction `AT_MOST`. This means I was free to change the width and height during every pass of onMeasure, and so I could end up calculating my aspect ratio as desired given the available area.

Haven't confirmed yet that this works for all cases, but hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2012/11/easy-measuring-of-custom-views-with-specific-aspect-ratio/) and a helper component to ease measuring custom Views with a fixed aspect ratio, if it helps anyone

Comment: Grafika's AspectFrameLayout class (https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java) demonstrates this; it's used for the various camera and video classes where maintaining the aspect ratio is very important.  Another approach is to use a TextureView and just tweak it's display matrix (e.g. `adjustAspectRatio()` in https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java ).

Answer (score 1):

To set the size of the SurfaceView you should use:

```
    // Set surfaceview size in px
private void setVideoSize(int width, int height) {
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) mYourSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height;
    params.width = width;
    mYourSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

And if you want to know the size of the screen:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int heigth = display.getHeight();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: From where are you calling setVideoSize? onCreate of the target view itself? Also rather than needing the size of the screen, I'd like to know the size of the available space that's not already claimed by the other views. I guess it could query every other view for their size and try to construct the available space having beforehand knowledge of their orientation, but that seems a little clunky.

Comment: You can call it from anywhere. If you want to fill the remaining part, you can use match_parent (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

Comment: Thing is is that I don't want to *match* the parent, I want to **know** the size of the parent. Depending on the size of the area to fill, I might want to match the width and leave empty space on top and bottom, or I might want to match the height and leave empty space on left and right. I can't do this by just filling the parent, otherwise I'll lose the required fixed aspect ratio. I do appreciate your suggestions though!

Comment: Hmm. Then you should do what you said before. Get the whole screensize and reduce it by the size of the other view.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of `ConstraintLayout` and Layout Editor, it becomes much easier to handle ratios.

Look at the XML snippet below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bckg" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#99000000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/someOtherView"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,2:3" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/someOtherView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#AAFFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

That's quite enough to achieve results you asked for. See screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will work i have tested.

```
public class Test_stflowActivity extends Activity {
    SurfaceView sv = null;
    RelativeLayout rl = null;
    int current_width = 0;
    int current_height   = 0;
    boolean already_created = false;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView1);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout3);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                current_height = rl.getHeight();
                while (current_height == 0) {
                    current_height = rl.getHeight();
                }
                current_width  = rl.getWidth();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        update_surface(current_height, current_width);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        already_created = false;
    }

    void update_surface(int current_height,int current_width) {
        if (already_created == false){

            // CALCULATE ASPECTED RATIO ACCORDING TO ABOVE HEIGHT AND WIDTH.
            int calculated_height = current_height/2;
            int calculated_width = current_width /2;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(calculated_height,
                                                                             calculated_width);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            sv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            already_created = true;
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Here is layout which i have created.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="87dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>





<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <android.view.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/SurfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:background="#ff0000" android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope help you to solve.