# How do you get the Android SurfaceView to be in 4:3?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm using Android's SurfaceView to display a live preview from the camera.  I'm using a relative layout and the preview on the surface view seems stretched out.  How do I force the surface view to show the preview in 4:3?

Comment: can you post your xml file? and what do you mean by 4:3?

Comment: I asked a very similar question, please read it and see if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510371/fill-remaining-space-with-fixed-aspect-ratio-surfaceview