# How to set fixed aspect ratio for a layout in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to set the width of the layout to "fill_parent" while having the height of the view just the same length, to make the layout a square.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: use wrap_content . It takes the same width and length the view has.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill remaining space with fixed aspect ratio surfaceview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510371/fill-remaining-space-with-fixed-aspect-ratio-surfaceview)

Comment: I struggled with this myself for a while, and eventually I decided I had to override the onMeasure of the view I wanted to constrain and set the dimensions programmatically. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Aren't the answers here closer to what you're looking for?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058507/fixed-aspect-ratio-view

Answer (score 114, accepted):

With introduction of [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) you don't have to write either a single line of code or use third-parties or rely on `PercentFrameLayout` which were deprecated in 26.0.0.

Here's the example of how to keep 1:1 aspect ratio for your layout using `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or instead of editing your XML file, you can edit your layout directly in Layout Editor:

[image: Layout Editor]

Comment: Hello @Eugene , whenever i use this to capture a video, the width always look kind of stretchy, what could have been the cause of this pls.

Answer (score 22):

In your *build.gradle* add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
```

and in your *layout.xml* **wrap** whatever view or viewgroup you want to to follow a ratio inside a [PercentFrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) where:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and then for the view or viewgroup you want to to follow a ratio **replace** *android:layout_width* and *android:layout_height*:

```
    app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
```

and you have a view or viewgroup where the aspect ratio is 16:9 (1.78:1) with the width matching the parent and the height adjusted accordingly.

Note: It's important you remove the normal width and height properties. Lint will complain, but it'll work.

Comment: I agree with everything said here except to remove the normal width and height properties that you mentioned is important. I've tried that and it didn't work for me. Instead I had to set them to the following android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp" as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931023/percentframelayout-you-must-supply-a-layout-width-attribute

Comment: Warning: this will only work if container width >= container height * 16/9. If for instance your container width is 1000dp, and its height 50dp, your child will fit the width and have a height of 1000*9/16=562.5.

Comment: `PercentRelativeLayout` and `PercentFrameLayout` are now deprecated and suggest using `ConstraintLayout` instead.

Answer (score 18):

You might try initially setting the `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. But from there I think you have to go into code. Just to experiment, in your activity try something like:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    findViewById(R.id.squareView).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override public void onGlobalLayout() {
            View squareView = findViewById(R.id.squareView);
            LayoutParams layout = squareView.getLayoutParams();
            layout.height = squareView.getWidth();
            squareView.setLayoutParams(layout);
            squareView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Where `R.id.squareView` is the `id` of the view in question. And note, this code is wrapped in the `onGlobalLayout` call to ensure that `squareView.getWidth()` has a meaningful value.

Comment: `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` is deprecated. use `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)`

Answer (score 6):

I created a layout library for similiar use case. Feel free to use it.

[RatioLayouts](https://github.com/riteshakya037/RatioLayouts)

## Installation

Add this to the top of the file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" 
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.ritesh:ratiolayout:1.0.0'
}
```

## Usage

Define 'app' namespace on root view in your layout

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Include this library in your layout

```
<com.ritesh.ratiolayout.RatioRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_ratio_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:fixed_attribute="WIDTH" // Fix one side of the layout 
        app:horizontal_ratio="2" // ratio of 2:3
        app:vertical_ratio="3">
```

Comment: it deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve aspect ratio and parent layout must be "wrap_content" (useful for text views with variable text), you can add a fake view, which keeps aspect ratio and other elements must be constrained to this view:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/ratio_constraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="122:246"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ratio_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ratio_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ratio_constraint"
        tools:text="The TextView which can extend the layout" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my development scenarios, I have to set fixed aspect ratio for a CardView whose parent is LinearLayout rather than ConstraintLayout. Then I found a universal solution to make an Android `View` maintain a fixed aspect ratio.

Within the `onMeasure()` method, we can calculate the desired width and height based on the desired aspect ratio and the available width and height provided by the layout system. Here's an example:

```
class FixedAspectRatioView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val height = (width / 1.618).roundToInt()
        val newHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeightMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```

The above code is for maintaining a fixed aspect ratio of approximately 1.618 for the `View`. Here's a breakdown of the code:

1. `val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)`: This line retrieves the available width from the `widthMeasureSpec` using `MeasureSpec.getSize()`. This width will be used to calculate the corresponding height based on the desired aspect ratio.
2. `val height = (width / 1.618).roundToInt()`: This line calculates the desired height by dividing the available width (`width`) by the desired aspect ratio (1.618). The result is rounded to the nearest integer using `roundToInt()`.
3. `val newHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)`: This line creates a new height measure specification (`newHeightMeasureSpec`) using `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec()`. The height is set to the calculated `height`, and the mode is set to `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`, indicating that the height should be exactly as specified.
4. `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeightMeasureSpec)`: This line calls the superclass's `onMeasure()` method with the original `widthMeasureSpec` and the new `newHeightMeasureSpec`. This ensures that the view is measured with the desired width and height, maintaining the fixed aspect ratio.

Overall, this code snippet should correctly maintain the fixed aspect ratio of approximately 1.618 for the `View`.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL);


int width = ll.getWidth();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
ll.setLayoutParams(ll_params);
```

Comment: This is more or less OK, however it all depends on *when* it is called. For example, if you were to put this code in onCreate, ll.getWidth() would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final RelativeLayout rlMyList = findViewById(R.id.rlMyList);
 rlMyList.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          int width = rlMyList.getWidth();
          LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) rlMyList.getLayoutParams();
          lp.width = width;
          lp.height = (int) (width * 0.67);// in my case ratio 3:2
          rlMyList.setLayoutParams(lp);
     }
 },500);
```

Answer (score -1):

set height as `fill_parent`, the width as `wrap_content`

and you fix the aspect ratio with `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: AdjustViewBounds is only applicable to ImageView, and it constrains the ratio of the drawable, not the ratio of the view.

Comment: so u want to make the layout SQUARE ?