# Rotate image from center point in imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to rotate an image in android. I found [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle) and it works great but it seems rotation in android starts from bottom left corner. I need to rotate my image from center point. Is it possible? Code for the same is helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with @goodm's solution is that imageView might not have been layed out yet which causes imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width() and .height() to return 0. That's why you're still rotating around 0,0. One way around this is to ensure you create and apply your matrix after layout using something like this: [How to set fixed aspect ratio for a layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311346/how-to-set-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-a-layout-in-android/12311431#12311431)

@Voicu's solution is ok, but it requires you to work directly with bitmaps which could be inefficient. Better might be to query the image resource directly for it's size, but not actually load it into memory. I use a utility method to do this, it looks like this:

```
public static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options getSize(Context c, int resId){
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options o = new android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), resId, o);
    return o;
}
```

This returns an Options object that will contain the actual width and height. From an Activity you could use it like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
Options o = getSize(this, R.drawable.yourImage);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(angle, o.outWidth/2, o.outHeight/2);
img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
img.setImageMatrix(m);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this (slightly different than goodm's answer):

```
public Bitmap rotateImage(int angle, Bitmap bitmapSrc) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSrc, 0, 0, 
            bitmapSrc.getWidth(), bitmapSrc.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: just stumbled upon this this as i am having similar problem! if you could help me, where would i load png image into this code?

Answer (score 3):

this is working for me:

```
RotateAnimation anim= new RotateAnimation(0f,350f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
```

// then set interpolator, duration, and RepeatCount

`yourImageView.startAnimation(anim);`

Comment: It's RotateAnimation, not RotationAnimation

Comment: hii what to do if i want to rotate an image from its bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

It's coming from the same answer what you gave a link.

Comment: Yes I saw this but it's wouldn't rotate from center point. should I add something? thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have a library that does this. You can find it here: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hg_dial_v2

Answer (score 0):

The answer by goodm given above works, just ensure you are getting the bounds etc. in the `onWindowFocusChanged()` activity life-cycle callback instead of `onCreate()`.

Because we need to ensure view has been rendered for the `getBounds()` functions to work correctly, else we get `0.0` as the values of these methods when calling them in `onCreate()`. `onWindowFocusChanged()` is the place where one can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for rotating image at 30 degree

```
 val rotateAnim = RotateAnimation(
        0.0f, 30F,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.19f,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f
    )
    rotateAnim.duration = 2000
    rotateAnim.fillAfter = true   
    yourImage.startAnimation(rotateAnim)
    rotateAnim.start();
```