# Android: How can I rotate an image from the center?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation

I'm trying to rotate this bitmap in the very center by "R0" degrees. But it doesn't rotate in the center. It rotates from the upper left corner.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Player ourView;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ourView = new Player(this);

        setContentView(ourView);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ourView.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ourView.resume();
    }
}
```

Here's the other class:

```
public class Player extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public Player(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
        try{
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread = null;
}

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(30, 30, 200);

                MainPlayer player = new MainPlayer();
                player.execute();

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }           
    }
}
```

And this is the class in which the bitmap gets rotated:

```
public class MainPlayer{

     Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
     Context context;
     float x=160;
     float y=455;
     float k=160;
     float l=455;
     float R0 = 150;

    public void execute(){
        draw();
    }

    public void draw(){

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        matrix.setRotate(R0);   

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);  
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);

    }
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527209/rotate-image-from-center-point-in-imageview this should work for you

Comment: Also this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point