# PercentFrameLayout: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-percent-library, android-percent-layout

I try to use a [PercentFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) but I get this error message:

```
Binary XML file line #: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

This is the xml I use:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Is this a bug or is it my mistake?

Comment: That looks exactly like the example at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html other than the order of parameters so I assume it is correct. Are you sure those are the views with the problem? If you remove those views does your layout load correctly?

Comment: @CoryCharlton yes it is from the doc and yes it is the view with the problem. Android Studio highlights it as a problem too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes are still required due to the XML layout specifications, but are effectively ignored in a `PercentFrameLayout` or `PercentRelativeLayout`.

You just have to set the values to `0dp` or `wrap_content`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
```

This is similar to the usage of a standard `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` where you have to specify a `layout_width` too.

Comment: But the doc says `It is not necessary to specify layout_width/height if you specify layout_widthPercent.`

Comment: @RalphBergmann That's weird, I couldn't even compile the XML without specifying the width/height.. So I'm not sure whether the docs are correct.

Comment: Looks like it IS necessary-- I've tried ommitting width/height (no exceptions thrown), and can only get it to render properly by setting both values to 0dp.