# Android:How to maintain aspect ratio of an entire app?

Tags: android

I would like to maintain a 9:16 aspect for the ENTIRE app, not a single view.
IE. on a 3:4 tablet,something like this:

[image]

I've tried using `PercentRelativeLayout` as the parent but that did not work.
What I've tried:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_aspectRatio="50%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    android:id="@+id/startmenu">
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I am using the 23.1.1 version of the library

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311346/how-to-set-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-a-layout-in-android

Comment: You will have to constraint your _root view_ to the aspect ratio that you expect. I'd take a look at the new ConstraintLayout, may be easier to try that route.