# How to Set Image Size Square.. Which Support in All Mobile Screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

**Item Layout**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_panel"
        android:background="@drawable/transback"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want to set image size square like
**screen width = image height**

this is my item which i use for recycler view

how it is possible..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise `ImageView` to create `SquareImageView`

```
public class SquareImageView  extends ImageView {

  public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use constraint layout** 
*app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"*

1. read [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#ratio)
2. see [example](https://medium.com/@sasanksunkavalli/android-constraintlayout-layout-constraintdimensionratio-33bd2293f34c)

Comment: You are only telling him how to make  the shape of the image - this will not be responsive to all screens

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image aspect ratio to 1:1 to achieve your square image like this:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />
```

If you want your screen to be responsive to all screen sizes you can use [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and give them some percents of your screen like this:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: is it possible in Relative Layout ?

Comment: It is possible, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311346/how-to-set-fixed-aspect-ratio-for-a-layout-in-android), but the best practice for this would be to use constraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

add those line on Android Mani fest

```
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
```

And this was my imageView

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Square Imageview

> Custom Imageview:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, w, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

> XML

```
 <yourpackagename.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_iv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```